# Why am I getting segmentational fault with weak_ptr

Tags: c++, c++17, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

I am doing an exercise to get to know the shared pointer and weak pointer.

So the example is with cyclic dependence of shared_ptr and how could I solve the problem with weak_ptr.

I want to initialize the root->left->parent to root and the same for right node but it is giving me segmentational fault.

Does anybody know something about this problem, how should I write and initialize it?

Here is my code.

Just to know, my first exercise was to do it all with only shared pointer, but after that to change parent to be the weak_ptr, so that's why there are commented lines

Thanks in advance

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Node {
    string name;
    shared_ptr<Node> left = nullptr;
    shared_ptr<Node> right = nullptr;
//    shared_ptr<Node> parent=nullptr; 
    weak_ptr<Node> parent;
    
    Node(string x) : name(x) { cout << "Constructor" << name << endl; }
    ~Node() { cout << "Destructor " << name << endl; }

    string toString() {
        string lStr{ "<none>" }, rStr{ "<none>" }, pStr{ "<none>" }; 

        if (left != nullptr) lStr = left->toString();
        if (right != nullptr) rStr = right->toString();
        
//      if (parent != nullptr) pStr = parent->name; 
        pStr = parent.lock()->name; 

        string res;
        res += "{Me:" + name + " ";
        res += "Parent:" + pStr + " "; 
        res += "Left:" + lStr + " ";
        res += "Right:" + rStr + "}";
        return res;
    }
    
};


shared_ptr<Node> foo() {
    shared_ptr<Node> root = make_shared<Node>("rootname");
    root->left = make_shared<Node>("leftname");
    root->right = make_shared<Node>("rightname");
    
    root->left->parent = {root};
    root->right->parent ={root};
    
    return root;
}

int main()
{
    shared_ptr<Node> k = foo();
    cout << k->toString() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When `parent.lock()` fails, `pStr = parent.lock()->name;` crashes.

Comment: You are telling me that parent is not the owner of the object in that moment. I don't understand why is that @Eljay

Comment: You previously got `if (parent != nullptr)` which handled the same case...

Comment: These kinds of problem are best resolved using a [debugger](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  Using a debugger is an invaluable skill for programming.

Comment: @Jarod42 that line was when I used shared_ptr, but I have read that when you use weak_ptr you cant ask if (p == nullptr) ...

Comment: control block is thread safe, so asking for `weak_ptr != 0` would be "meaningless", as next line, the block might be destroyed. `lock()` ensures that your `std::shared_ptr` is valid as long as you keep it alive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//      if (parent != nullptr) pStr = parent->name; 
        pStr = parent.lock()->name;
```

should be

```
    if (auto parentPtr = parent.lock()) pStr = parentPtr->name;
```

`parent.lock()` might return null `std::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

It crashes at this line:

```
pStr = parent.lock()->name;
```

because `parent` is not initialized for the root node. I do not know what your logic for the root item is, but you must check the result of lock, and if it is not valid do smth else with pStr.

```
if (auto res = parent.lock()) {
    pStr = res->name;
} else {
    pStr = "root";
}
```

Comment: can you tell me is the problem with shared_ptr in this code (without weak_ptr) that he is not calling destructors because he can't finish the loop of linked shared pointers?